# Azure Managed Identity and Azure Private Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity, azure-private-link

I am trying to design an app using Azure app services and Azure SQL database. I can connect to Azure MS SQL Server from Azure app service via Managed Identity or via Private link (Azure Private Endpoint). However, I am unable to understand the exact difference which one should be preferred over other and for what use-cases?

In both the cases, the traffic will flow over the azure back-bone. In addition, what I understood is that both can be leveraged simultaneously i.e. provision Azure MS SQL Server as Managed Identity and connect to this SQL Server via Private Endpoint. Would like to know the additional benefits we are getting buy leveraging both.

Answer (score 1):

Both Managed Identity and Azure Private Endpoint are security features in Azure that can be used to enhance the security of your application when connecting to Azure SQL Database.

**Managed Identity:**

- Managed Identity allows your App Service to authenticate to Azure SQL Database using a system-assigned identity or a user-assigned identity. This eliminates the need to store credentials in your application code or configuration files.
- No need to manage and rotate credentials manually.
- Simplifies security by removing the need for application-level credentials.
- Automatically handles token acquisition and renewal.
- for reference check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/context/msi-context.json&tabs=portal,http).

**Azure Private Endpoint:**

- Private Link enables you to access your Azure SQL Database over a   private, dedicated connection instead of over the internet. This   improves security by keeping traffic within the Azure backbone and   reduces exposure to public internet threats.
- Improved   security by connecting to Azure SQL Database via a private, dedicated connection.
- Reduced exposure to the public internet and potential
  attacks.
- Allows you to access Azure SQL Database using private IP addresses.
- For reference check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-private-endpoint).
- **Enhanced Security:** By combining Managed Identity with Private Link, you achieve a multi-layered security approach. Managed Identity ensures secure authentication, and Private Link ensures that the data transfer occurs over a private network.
- **Least Privilege Access:** You can configure the Azure SQL Database to only accept connections from specific Private Link services, reducing the attack surface further.
- **Compliance Requirements:** In some cases, you might have specific compliance requirements that mandate a combination of these features for secure data access.

For Refence for Managed Identity with Private endpoint check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/managed-identities-secured-access?view=doc-intel-4.0.0).

Comment: Thanks Vivek for sharing your views. will go through Azure reference document